# Using Custom Attributes to Populate Members from IDataReader

Tags: c#, database

Just learned how to use custom attributes in C# and the first useful thing I did with it was to make a class object representing a database table. The constructor can accept an `IDataReader` and populate the members based on the custom attribute. Is this a good usage of custom attributes?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DatabaseField: Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DatabaseField( string name )
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    [DatabaseField("Employee_ID")]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [DatabaseField("LogonId")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DatabaseField("Email")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [DatabaseField("NAME")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [DatabaseField("First_Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DatabaseField("Middle_Name")]
    public string MiddeName { get; set; }

    [DatabaseField("Last_Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DatabaseField("Name_Suffix")]
    public string NameSuffix { get; set; }

    [DatabaseField("Job_Title")]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    [DatabaseField("Department")]
    public string Department { get; set; }

    [DatabaseField("Emp_Type")]
    public string EmployeeType { get; set; }

    [DatabaseField("SupervisorID")]
    public string ManagerId { get; set; }

    public Employee( IDataReader reader )
    {
        foreach( PropertyInfo prop in typeof(Employee).GetProperties() )
        {
            foreach( object attr in prop.GetCustomAttributes(true) )
            {
                DatabaseField field = attr as DatabaseField;
                if( null != field )
                {
                    object value = reader[field.Name];
                    prop.SetValue(this, value == DBNull.Value ? null : value, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own ORM?

Comment: @svick, because I'm primarily self taught and did not know about ORM until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class DatabaseField: Attribute
```

According to [the naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040), the names of attribute classes should end with `Attribute`, so this class should be called `DatabaseFieldAttribute`.

---

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I don't see any reason why the setter should be public, so I would make it private.

---

```
public Employee( IDataReader reader )
```

I don't think all this code should be here. Instead, it should be in a library that's not specific to your types.

---

Have you considered adding the knowledge of your naming conventions to your code, so that not all properties need the attribute?

Also, I would go the other way around: for each column in the reader, find the appropriate property to set. That way, if your type is missing a property, you can learn about it.

---

```
foreach( object attr in prop.GetCustomAttributes(true) )
```

I would use [the generic extension method `GetCustomAttribute<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138307) here, to simplify your code:

```
var attr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<DatabaseFieldAttribute>(true);
```

---

```
if( null != field )
```

There is not reason to use [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) in C#. The issue they're addressing is that buggy code like `if (field = null)` is valid C and C++. But it's not valid C#.

Comment: **+1** Good answers. The Yoda conditions are just habit. I started out with C/C++. Unfortunately, I neither had nor have any say in the design of the database. I chose to go through each property rather than through each field in the `IDataReader` because if one of the class properties is missing, then that tells me the code is being used improperly on the wrong database and we don't want that.

Comment: @druciferre: You could check both (perfect mapping) in debug compilation (e.g. by [Debug.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) used on number of props seen)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @svick suggestions (which are all good), here's a couple of feedback:

- While this approach can work, it has a couple of flaws. First, your model is now polluted with knowledge of the database, I'd suggest you don't use custom attributes for this, and instead of a class that's specialized in mapping between model and database.
- You should prefer a naming convention, so your mapping logic can guess what the column name is based on the property name, so you don't have a need for an attribute at all in 99% of cases
- Use of custom attribute (or better yet, your mapper should handle the special cases) when property names/column names don't follow default conventions
- You can simplify your reflection code for reading the custom attribute data by leveraging linq to make your code cleaner and more readable:

  Example:

  ```
  typeof(Employee).GetProperties()
                  .SelectMany(prop => prop.GetCustomAttribute<DatabaseFieldAttribute>(true))
                  .ForEach(attr => {
                      var value = reader[field.Name];
                      prop.SetValue(this, value == DBNull.Value ? null : value, null);
                  });
  ```
- As @svick mentions, you should move the reflection code out of your model, into your framework/infrastructure code somewhere. Models should generally be dumb.
- I would likely recommend you use an existing Object Relational Mapping (ORM) tool for this work instead of rolling your own, as there are many advantages to doing so.

  Examples:

  - [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/)
  - [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

Comment: I would completely agree about the naming convention, but unfortunately the database I'm working with is already in place, and I neither had nor have any control over its design.